# PY, JS Chrome Extension Receiving Events From Python

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a python script that sends events to a chrome extension when at intervals. I want the python script to send an event to the chrome extension which is listener for an event and will act accordingly based on the data.

I'm not looking for a code solution, I'm just wondering how this could be achieved. Something like below. Would something like sockets be used for this?

Python

```py
send_event({"data": []})
```

JS

```js
on_receive_event(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: I'm trying to connect over web not application, is it possible to do that with Native Messaging?

Comment: No, nativeMessaging is for local machine. For web communication you'll have to use an intermediate server so that the extension polls its endpoint periodically.

Comment: Yea, I was trying to avoid fetching periodically for a response... There's no way to do it with websockets or something?